# jenkins job skipped due to when conditional and how to avoid notification as success

Tags: jenkins

I created a jenkins job, which is executes build step when conditions met else job will skipped.

stage script is like this

```
 stage('build') {
    when {
        anyof {
          changeset "**/*.js"
          changeset "**/*.xml"
          triggeredBy cause: "UserIdCause"
       }
    }
    steps{
      build script
    }
 }
```

If any of condition is true, build step will executed else job will be skipped.

output looks like:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] echo
Warning, empty changelog. Have you run checkout?
[Pipeline] echo
Warning, empty changelog. Have you run checkout?
[Pipeline] echo
Warning, empty changelog. Have you run checkout?
[Pipeline] echo
Warning, empty changelog. Have you run checkout?
Stage "build" skipped due to when conditional
```

Job status is success for skipped builds too.

I don't want to notify the team when build step skipped due to "**when condition**". How to achieve this. notifying teams via slack from post - success section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this in post section

```
post {
  always {
    script {
      if ("${currentBuild.currentResult}" != 'SUCCESS') {
        # add the logic of sending email to developers
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Job result is success even, stage is skipped.